# Running R code containing spaces from Windows Command Line

Tags: r, rscript

I need to run R code from the command line, but a path containing a space breaks the command.

This code runs fine:

```
Rscript -e "x=1;write.csv(x,'H:/this_folder/x.csv')"
```

While this code:

```
Rscript -e "x=1;write.csv(x,'H:/that folder/x.csv')"
```

returns:

*'C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-34~1.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" -e "x' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

What syntax should be used here? Is there a way to escape the space?

Comment: Did you try `Rscript -e 'x=1;write.csv(x, file = "H:/that folder/x.csv")'`

Comment: Yes, it returns the same error as above.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this problem; 
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin>Rscript -e "x=1;write.csv(x,'delete me/x.csv')"

C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin>dir "delete me"
 Directory of C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\delete me

02/09/2018  06:31 PM    <DIR>          .
02/09/2018  06:31 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/09/2018  06:31 PM                15 x.csv

Comment: I was using that in Linux terminal. It worked for me. must be replated to windows then.

Comment: Working for me using these lines in `cmd` (cmder) under Windows 10:   
`Rscript -e "x=1;write.csv(x,'c:/this_folder/x.csv')"`   
and    
`Rscript -e "x=1;write.csv(x,'c:/that folder/x.csv')"` (after manually creating the folder in Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so that is the correct syntax in the Windows command line as well. The issue is with the current version of R (3.4.3). The above command works fine with the previous version (3.4.2). Specifically, this issue applies to this version of Rscript:

**C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe'**

The original command works fine using these versions:

**C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe**

**C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe**

Thanks to those who tried it on different systems.